# Should cultural references/expressions be edited to more "standard" language?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently read [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/13134/2579) to a question on Interpersonal Skills.SE. One paragraph is as follows (emphasis mine):

> First of all, there's nothing wrong asking to change school or instructor. A efficient pedagogy needs at least 2 very important factors. One is the quality of theoretical explanations and practical exercices, the second is **the relationship between the Jedi and the Padawan**.

This could be rephrased, by removing cultural references, to "***the relationship between the teacher and the student***".

Not everyone has watched Star Wars, so they might not get the reference or be able to infer the meaning. This might (probably?) be even more difficult for those whose native language isn't English.

Should these types of cultural references be edited in favor of "plain" English?

Comment: Hmm, I think this puts us between Scylla and Charybdis.

Comment: If close-voters/down-voters could comment on *why* this question isn't relevant, or could be improved, that would be great!

Comment: I'm curious about the close votes. Even though the example was taken from IPS.SE, the issue applies to every SE sites.

Comment: @HTTPS It seems to me that meta is *I don't understand or like this proposal, therefore downvote and close vote*. Maybe I don't understand *meta* that well, but an upvote means *this is something we should talk about/worthwile to consider* and a downvote means *this is already understood/no need to worry*. Who knows. My question remains though: should this language be edited? On SciFi.SE obviously "Jedi and Padawan" would be understood... but by users on ELL.SE? I don't think so, not so unanimously. So yeah, I am also confused by the close votes...

Comment: As someone who uses quite a few references - I do think that its an issue that transcends a single site. Totally would vote to reopen if it got closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just my 2 cents: it depends.

Sometimes, it's useful to have an analogy/metaphor; those can be a tremendous help in understanding the situation. It's also some kind of 'artistic freedom' we allow our contributors. What *might* help is adding a link to e.g. a Wikipedia article so that people who don't know about  Jedi (wait? do those people exist?) can obtain background information about the topic and understand the analogy.

If you feel the example is so obscure that less than 10% of the audience will 'get' it, and can be changed into something more neutral/easily understood which is still applicable, I'd say go for it.

Comment: I think it's a pretty hard limit to require 90% not understand a statement before doing something about it. 10% *not* understanding is enough to justify an explanation, let alone half, let alone 90%.

Comment: @Nij agreed, I was merely sketching the extremes. There's a lot of gray area in between.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I think to a *certain extent* the author's voice is essential here. If it's something *intensely obscure* (like [Babylon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5) references) asking for clarification might help find a good common ground. I actually feel that's a good use for comments. And in some cases, catch a confusing, almost correct typo...

I really do think on *many* sites and in many contexts the appropriate use of cultural metaphors and references can enhance a post.

I also suspect with a 'policy' of it, some folks may go a little over-zealous, and it might end up being a net loss.

Comment: Babylon 5 is obscure?  Zathras sad.  Zathras have sad life. Probably sad death, but at least there is symmetry.

Comment: Hmm. Should I have said space ABY or earth final conflict?:p

Answer (score 1):

As you are preparing to put on your editor hat:

- Watch the comments.  They will give you a useful clue as to how well people are understanding the post.
- Watch the site in general, including its Meta, to find out what the general level of understanding of metaphors and subtleties is at the particular site, along with the level of tolerance of not-so-essential edits.  (This varies from site to site.)
- Spend some time at each session reading other people's successful edits; notice the changes made, and also the "reason," that documents the edit.

If you would like to venture an edit, here are some tips I have figured out (sometimes through editing experiences of my own that didn't go so great):

- put the vanilla English in parentheses, or make a footnote explanation; that is, do not remove the post author's carefully chosen colorful expressions
- leave a tactful comment below the post, such as "Please check my edit" to show humility and deference; if the author is a newcomer, and you have enough rep to edit without review, explain further, such as "Please check my edit, and don't hesitate to click where it says 'Edit,' to the left of your post, below the score, to "roll back" to your original version"
- clearly document what you did and why before submitting your edit
- study how others document their edits, and emulate the best documenters
- don't take it personally if the author reverts the post to the previous version; do not waste people's time discussing your rejected edit

By the way, your proposed edit in your example seems like overediting to me although I would want to see the cultural context of the particular site, and the rest of the post, to see if the general idea is still understandable.

Comment: what Anne did to my answer was brilliant by the way - she basically added a link to what I was referring to. Also edits notify anyway so having the commentary in the edit-reasons should be good enough.